# restriction of unitary operator is unitary?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathcal{U}: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ be a unitary operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.  If $\mathcal{K}\subset \mathcal{H}$ is a closed subspace such that $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{K})\subset \mathcal{K}$, is it necessarily the case that $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{K})=\mathcal{K}$?    Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not the case.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Thank you, young man :) Do you have a counter example?

Comment: I'm still thinking of one, but I remember that $\mathcal{U(K)}=K$ was not always the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal H$ be the Hilbert space of square summable sequences indexed by $\mathbb Z$, so $$\mathcal H = \{ (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z} \, | \, \sum_n |a_n|^2 < \infty \}.$$

Let $U : \mathcal H \to \mathcal H$ be the shift operator $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z} \mapsto (a_{n-1})_{n \in \mathbb Z}$.  If $\mathcal K$ denotes the subspace
of sequences such that $a_n  = 0$ if $n < 0$, then $\mathcal K$ is invariant under $U$, but $U$ is not surjective when restricted to $\mathcal K$.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Clearly I just don't know enough examples of unitary operators.

Comment: Dear Flynt, It is helpful to think that unitary operators come in two flavours --- diagonalizable, and ``shift type'' operators.  (Of course, this is a gross simplification, since these sorts of behaviours could be combined in complex ways in a single operator, but it's a helpful mental model.)  If $U$ is just acting as multiplication by scalars on various eigenspaces, then in your question, $\mathcal K$ would have to be a sum of certain eigenspaces, and then $U$ would act subjectively on $\mathcal K$ too.  So it's natural to turn to shift-type operators to look for a counterexample.   Cheers,

Comment: @FlyntFloss: P.S. I should also have said "you're welcome".  One more comment: a set-theoretic version of your question would be: given a bijection on a set $S$, it $T$ is an invariant subset, does the bijection necessarily restrict to a bijection on $T$ as well.  We know that the answer is *no*, basically by the same example as in my answer: just consider translation by $1$, which is a bijection on $\mathbb Z$ but is not a bijection when restricted to $\mathbb N$.  Shift operators allow you to transfer these combinatorial/set-theoretic observations to the world of unitary operators, ...

Comment: ... since shift-type operators are obtained just by using the given set as the basis for a Hilbert space, and then defining the operator just via the action on the labels for the basis elements.